# I need helping in displaying data in a table having horizontal scrollbar

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have much data to show in a UITableView's each row.Client want to see data any how on same table not on next view.so i decided to use horizontal scroll in every row so that i can show all the data.
I need help in creating table with scrollview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableView itself has scrollview. You are confusing actually you need variable size UITableViewCells to display all data in a cell. Search on google or stackoverflow to display all data in tableViewCell. Let me google it for you http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/

Answer (score 0):

You can take UIScrollView and take UITableView inside that, you can set its width according to your requirement, and set contentSize of scrollView

Answer (score 0):

I think you can increase the cell row height to fit in your content inside it. May be you can display the title with higher font size and the description in a lesser font size as done in many of the iPhone applications.

Comment: i need to increase the width because it takes more space if i increase height'